# Defining number of threads on HTTP Requester configurations/connectors

Tags: multithreading, mule, mule-studio

I'm trying to control the amount of maxThreadsActive and maxThreadsIdle for outgoing HTTP connections in Mule.

Setting the default-threading-profile doesn't affect the amount of threads that are allocated HTTP requesters.

For HTTP listeners it's possible to set the threading profile via the http:worker-threading-profile, like this:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration">
    <http:worker-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="2" maxThreadsIdle="1" threadTTL="60000"/>
</http:listener-config>
```

But i can't find a way to apply a threading profile on a http:request element.

Besides this i'm wondering how the http:worker-threading-profile in this case works for listeners, when i use a profiler (VisualVM) i don't see any changes in the amount of threads that are allocated for the HTTP listener.

Any ideas regarding threads for HTTP endpoints and how to control them and verify it?

Screenshot below is from a simple test app with the threading profile applied as mentioned above.

[image]

The same app has a simple http:request config, for an outbound HTTP connection (requester) i always get this number of threads:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it myself, but some info from research and training says this: If your flow is using a [synchronous processing strategy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/flow-processing-strategies#summary), which Mule sets based on your message source and flow behavior, processing is done in the same thread. This might explain why you don't see any changes in the amount of threads that are allocated for the HTTP listener. The flow is set to synchronous if the message source is request-response--sender of the message is expecting a response or the flow is involved in a [transaction](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/transaction-management#applying-a-transaction-to-a-connector).

Otherwise, Mule sets the flow to queued-asynchronous. In this case you set threads using the flow's properties view (in Studio, select the flow itself and look for Processing Strategy in the properties). Set properties for the flow as [described in the docs.](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/flow-processing-strategies#fine-tuning-a-queued-asynchronous-processing-strategy) You do not set threads for the HTTP Requester afaik.